# Is javascript still running after alert message pop out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var idleTime = 1;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
     var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 5000); // 5 seconds

     //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
     $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
         idleTime = 1;
     });
     $(this).keypress(function (e) {
         idleTime = 1;
     });
 });

 function timerIncrement() {
     idleTime = idleTime + 1;
     if (idleTime == 2) { // 10 seconds
       alert("10 seconds");
       // alert("19分鐘沒動靜！");
     }
     else if(idleTime == 3) { // 15 seconds
      window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
     }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I want to do is to detect idle time, if 10 seconds passed, will pop out a alert message.if idle time keep counting to 15 seconds, the page will directly redirect to the url.

But it seems like after alert message, the rest of code did not run.

Comment: Yes, alert will halt the code execution. That is why console.log is there.

Answer (score 2):

The alert() function will stop JS execution.  If you want to communicate with the user to warn them about an impending timeout, I would suggest making your own Notification with a `<div>` or something like that.